# How to receive location info when receiving a proximity alert intent?

Tags: android, gps, location

I need to add more than one proximity alert with addProximityAlert method from LocationManager. The problem is that when i receive the intent informing that the user is near to one of the regions that i am listening for alerts i can get if the user is entering or exiting in a region reading KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING, but i dont know what is the region he is entering or exiting. Is there any way the get this kind of info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, to add a ProximityAlert you need a PendingIntent, a PeindingIntent can be obtained with PendingIntent.getBroadcast(aContext, aRequestCode, anIntent, 0);  Now, in the third parameter 'anIntent' you can put any data you want, like a Location object, a city name obtained with the location,

i do this like this:

```
private static final float DEFAULT_PROXIMITY = 1000f;
int requestCode = 0;
for (Location p : locationList) {
                Double _lat = p.getLatitude();
                Double _lon = p.getLongitude();
                float radious = DEFAULT_PROXIMITY;
                long expiration = -1;

                Intent intent = new Intent(PROXIMITY_ALERT_ACTION_FIRED);
                intent.putExtra( "location-lat" , p.getLatitude());
                intent.putExtra( "location-lon" , p.getLongitude());
                PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, requestCode, intent, 0);
                locationManager.addProximityAlert(_lat, _lon, radious, expiration, proximityIntent);
                requestCode++;
            }
```

now, when you receive the broadcast message, you must obtain the location info from the passed intent, something like this;

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

  Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);
  if(entering){
    long lat = intent.getLongExtra("location-lat", -1);
    long lon = intent.getLongExtra("location-lon", -1);
    log.info("", "entering: " + lat + lon);
  }else{
    long lat = intent.getLongExtra("location-lat", -1);
    long lon = intent.getLongExtra("location-lon", -1);
    log.info("", "exiting: " + lat + lon);

  }
}
```

cheers

Comment: That was perfect. Is it possible to identify the location provider that triggered the alert. GPS_PROVIDER or NETWORK_PROVIDER @Franco

Answer (score 0):

Define multiple Actions for every region you are interested in